# merge two records into a single record

Tags: java, excel, python-2.7, plsql

Suppose, I need to perform cleanup on a raw data in excel format.

ID, Name, amount, Date, Flag

Suppose record 1 is
123, saif, 50$, 3rd March 2016, Yes

Record 2 is
123, saif, 150$, 8th March 2016, No

I need to merge two records with same id like below.

The final single merge record should be
123, saif, 200$, 8th Mar, No

I need the Data to be manipulated and merged into the most recent record (by date).

Should I use PL SQL after pushing data into database or use Excel Macros or VBA or manipulate data using java or python?

Comment: What if the same ids are having different names? Is the amount added up? What about the logic for Flag? When should it be No or Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it whit PL/SQL, something like this:

1. Create the table with data if you don't have it:

[image]

2. Create a temporary function that help with returning the latest flag:

[image]

3. Make a group query that call the temporary function to get the data:

[image]